# Modular and congruence prove

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Let $p$ be a prime and $a \in \Bbb Z$, how to prove that the congruence $x^2 \equiv a \pmod p$ has at most two solutions $\bmod p$?
I have no idea how to start. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: $x^2=a \Rightarrow x^2-a=0=(x-a)(x+a)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* If $u$ and $v$ are solutions of $x^2 \equiv a \bmod p$, then $p$ divides $u^2-a$ and $v^2-a$ and so divides their difference, $u^2-v^2=(u+v)(u-v)$.

Can you take it from here? If not, see the solution below.

> Since $p$ is prime, it must divide one of the factors. This means that $u \equiv \pm v \bmod p$, and so there are at most $2$ solutions.